# print the line on which text occurs using grep bash

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to grep a file for certain text, and output ONLY the line number on which it occurs. Example:

File.text:

```
firstsentance
secondsentance
thirdsentance
```

if I grep for secondsentance I should receive an output of 2.

Comment: each of the words in file.text are supposed to be in their own row, not the same row.

Answer (score 6):

This will do what you want:

```
sed -n '/secondsentence/=' File.text
```

Perl:

```
perl -lne 'print $. if /secondsentence/' File.text
```

Comment: I like this because the option `=` is not widely used, besides of avoiding to use pipes, **+1**

Comment: Great answer. I'd also like to mention that if one only wants the first match, you can bail out after the match is found. `sed -n '/secondsentence/ { =; q }'`

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that `grep` itself has such a feature, but you could write:

```
grep -n secondsentance File.text | sed 's/:.*//'
```

to strip off everything from the `:` onward.

Note that this will not have the same exit-code as `grep` alone.

Comment: My answer was very similar but using `cut`, like: `... | cut -d: -f1`, so **+1**

Answer (score 2):

Try to learn AWK :

```
awk '/secondsentance/ { print NR }' file.text
```

Answer (score 1):

And an awk solution.

```
awk '/secondsentance/ { print NR }' file
```